# Checking empty user textboxes and adding error messages

Tags: javascript, html

In my program I want to ask users their name, and number of pets. If the user enters an empty string, I want a error message to prompt the user to type something in, and fill the text box with input. Currently I cannot check the text box, and my code is displaying the error message of "Please type your first name" even if text is put in.  Don't know exactly how to fix this.

```js
var $ = function (id)
{
 return document.getElementById(id);
}
var processInfo = function ()
{
 //Setting varibles from HTML
 first = $('firstname');
 last = $('lastname');
 petnum = $('numpets');
 firsterror = $('firstname_error');
 lasterror = $('lastname_error');
 petnumerror = $('numpets_error');

 //Checking for blank strings to be filled
 var errorFoundFlagFirst = 'N';
 var errorFoundFlagLast = 'N';
 var errorFoundFlagPet = 'N';
 var errmsgfirst = '';
 var errmsglast = '';
 var errmsgpet = '';
 if (firsterror === '')
 {
  errorFoundFlagFirst = 'Y';
 }
 if (lasterror === '')
 {
  errorFoundFlagLast = 'Y';
 }
 if (petnumerror === '')
 {
  errorFoundFlagPet = 'Y';
 }
 

 if (errorFoundFlagFirst = 'Y')
 {
  errmsgfirst = 'Please enter your first name. ';
 } else {
  errmsgfirst = '';
  }
 if (errorFoundFlagLast = 'Y')
 {
  errmsglast = "Please enter your last name. ";
 } else {
  errmsglast = '';
  }
 if (errorFoundFlagPet = 'Y')
 {
 errmsgpet = "Please enter the number of pets. ";
 } else {
 errmsgpet = '';
  }


 //For loop for pet names - Currently will take Pet names and put them in PetList with spaces.
 var Petlist = '';
 for (cntr = 1; cntr <= petnum.value; cntr++)
 {
 petID = 'pet' + cntr;
 PetName = $(petID).value + ' ';
 Petlist += PetName;
 }



$("msg").innerHTML = Petlist;
$("errormsgfirst").innerHTML = errmsgfirst;
$("errormsglast").innerHTML = errmsglast;
$("errormsgpet").innerHTML = errmsgpet;


}

window.onload = function ()
{
$("mybutton").onclick = processInfo;
}
```

```html
<h1>Assignment 2</h1>
<p>Enter First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname"> <span id="firstname_error"></span></p>
<p>Enter Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname"> <span id="lastname_error"></span>
</p>
<p>How Many Pets do you have? (0-3): <input type="text" id="numpets" size="1" maxlength="1">
<span id="numpets_error"></span>
</p>
<p>List your Pet's names:
<input type="text" id="pet1">
<input type="text" id="pet2">
<input type="text" id="pet3">
</p>
<p><input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Submit Information"></p>
<p id="errormsgfirst"></p>
<p id="errormsglast"></p>
<p id="errormsgpet"></p>
<p id="msg"></p>
```

I eventually want to put all the data into one string to display, but so far I cannot get the proper messages to display at the right times.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic has couple of issues.

1. Accessing values of text box
2. Incorrect variables being tested for being empty.

To access values for an input use something like

```
// Gets you the value of the input 
first = $('firstname').value;
```

Check if the field is empty by using the value attribute on the input. You are currently using checking for the value of spans where you error will possibly display.

```
// this is your Current code which is incorrect
if (firsterror === '') { errorFoundFlagFirst = 'Y'; }
```

Replace above with below:

```
if (first === '') { errorFoundFlagFirst = 'Y'; }
```

I'd recommend you going through your logic again!

Answer (score 0):

You are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Rather than typing up a bunch of code and logic for empty fields, let the browser do the work for you by designating them as `required`. I added a function that will create the pet inputs dynamically.

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var element = document.getElementById('pet-items');

function createPets() {
  element.innerHTML = '';
  for(i = 1; i <= this.value; i++) {
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('id', 'pet' + i);
    input.required = true;
    
    element.append(input);
  }
}

document.getElementById('numpets').addEventListener('input', createPets);

var processInfo = function() {
  //Setting varibles from HTML
  first = $('firstname');
  last = $('lastname');
  numpets = $('numpets');

  //For loop for pet names - Currently will take Pet names and put them in PetList with spaces.
  var Petlist = '';
  for (cntr = 1; cntr <= numpets.value; cntr++) {
    petID = 'pet' + cntr;
    PetName = $(petID).value + ' ';
    Petlist += PetName;
  }

  $("msg").innerHTML = Petlist;
}

window.onload = function() {
  $("mybutton").onclick = processInfo;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color: silver">
  <h1>Assignment 2</h1>
  <form id="myform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <p>Enter First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" required></p>
    <p>Enter Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" required></p>
    <p>How Many Pets do you have? (0-3): <input type="text" id="numpets" size="1" maxlength="1" required>
    </p>
    <p>List your Pet's names:
      <span id="pet-items"></span>
    </p>
    <p><input id="mybutton" type="submit" value="Submit Information"></p>
  </form>
  <p id="msg"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: S/He is not using jquery, his $ function is just an alias for document.getElementById.

Comment: @cloned - I see now